# Troubleshoot the reason for SMTP

Tags: smtp

'm unable to send the emails from my server, nagios.emoney.com, to relay host with smtp protocol. I took tcpdump towards, v-smtpgw5.ka.kasnova.net cmsmtp, and foudn the following ERROR:-

220 v-smtpgw5.ka.kasnova.net cmsmtp ESMTP server ready
EHLO nagios.emoney.com
250-v-smtpgw5.ka.kasnova.net hello [192.176.46.25], pleased to meet you
250-HELP
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
250-SIZE 157286400
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 OK
MAIL FROM: SIZE=23469
550 5.1.0 hajYZDVLAFhmqhajYZZnfF Sender Domain Rejected [403]
RSET 250 2.0.0 OK
QUIT
221 2.0.0 v-smtpgw5.ka.kasnova.net cmsmtp closing connection

Can anyone please help to identify what is wrong here ?

Comment: Looks like that smtp server doesn't want to act as an relay for your domain. The problem is at the server-side, not in your client.

Comment: any fix that you suggest to make it act ?

Comment: Yes, call the admins of that smtp server to allow your domain to be relayed? Or use another smtp server, for example google/gmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason it refuses to relay for your domain because your mail program apparently never says what address you're sending from in the `MAIL FROM:` statement.  Notice how there isn't an email address afterwards, and it just jumps straight in to the `SIZE=23469`?  This is referred to as a null path.  This is valid syntax according to the RFC, but many mail servers will reject sending on behalf of an unknown address.

You didn't say what program is generating the mail, but if you configure a "send as" email address in the program, it should use it in the SMTP conversation.  It would look more like:

```
MAIL FROM: <johndoe@emoney.com> SIZE=23469
```

or

```
MAIL FROM: John Doe<johndoe@emoney.com> SIZE=23469
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot relay email through an SMTP server without first authenticating.  A user name and password is required.

Comment: Unless it is an open relay due to bad configuration